# PHP String comparison fails

Tags: php

Even if the  value of a key in an array is same as hard coded string the comparison results to false.

```
$json_array = json_decode($data,true);

$client_id = $json_array['ClientId']; //the value is ApiIntegration

echo $client_id== "ApiIntegration";
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($json_array['ClientId']);` output? Might be some spaces there, or something

Comment: Make sure `$client_id` has been defined and that you are not un-setting it or changing it somewhere else. Also check to see if you have valid JSON.

Comment: A string comparision in php certainly _does_ work. You can be assured of that. So the question is: what is it that surprises you in your own code? You will have to add much more details to your question for us to help...

Comment: You didn't check if `json_decode` succeeded. You didn't check if `ClientId` is an index that exists in the array, if the array was created at all. You didn't provide the raw json for us to inspect. PHP comparison is working, it's your data that's wrong. Given the fact you didn't help us reproduce the error, what can we do?